# selenium java modifications to the dom, how to reload the page to display modifications

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

0

I have a driver in java selenium :

```
driver.get(url);
```

I have made some changes to a WebElement with this method :

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='';", element);
```

How do I reload the page with the modifications ? I have tried driver.navigate.refresh() but that doesn't work.

Thank you for your ideas

Comment: Okay, so you added an attribute to a web element  using JavaScript executer and then you wish to refresh the page. What do you want the resulting effect to be in the page? Should the page reset the element and clear the value attribute? Should the value be retained in the element? What purpose are you trying to achieve with this scenario?

Comment: I want to edit the text of a element to "". Then I want the page to show the new text, by reload or other mean.

Comment: Usually how JavaScript and HTML work is after filling in data in any form element, if you reload the page without submitting the form, the form elements get reset. Unless specifically designed to show the same form with data on submit, the form would redirect user to the next step after submit whatever it may be. It is possible that some JQuery or Ajax script is written to retain the data in the form on reload, or data is stored in local cache or database, in such a case you should be able to see the updated data. There can also be other possibilities. How's your form designed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Addressing challenges in automation scripts is a common aspect of software testing, In addressing issues where modifications to the DOM are not immediately reflected after using Selenium in Java.

This automation strategy is crucial in maintaining the stability and reliability of automation scripts, a key consideration in software qa company.

**Approach:**
The refresh method typically reloads the page without using the cache, but it might not reapply the modifications you made with JavaScript.

The issue can be resolved if navigate back to the same URL after making the modifications.

**Here's the code snippet for it:**

```
// Store the current URL
String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();

// Make modifications to the WebElement
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='';", element);

// Navigate back to the same URL
driver.get(currentUrl);
```

This way, you are navigating back to the same URL, triggering a reload, and your modifications should be applied.